# Checking mapping between 2 xml files

Tags: xml

I'm testing a BizTalk interface that receives a soap request and uses the information from the request to call another service.

I need to check that the data in the first soap request is mapped to the correct elements in the new request. Currently I am exporting both to xml files and manually comparing them

Is there a good open source tool or a way to check this mapping without manually checking?

Comment: Can you remove the part where you ask for a tool? [Tool recommendations are off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. (Whenever you got a few minutes to spare, please read the introductory [tour].)

Answer (score 1):

You could use XSLT to create output files from your inputs and then compare them to Biztalk’s outputs. But then you would need to validate your XSLT manually anyway... Kind of overkill and beats the purpose.

I think the simplest way is:

1. Prepare inputs for relevant scenarios
2. Feed the inputs to Biztalk
3. Validate the outputs manually
4. Keep the validated input/outputs pairs for regression testing

This way next time you need to run these tests you can just compare the actual VS expected outputs with some text comparison tool (I used Notepad++ but I’m sure you can find some smart XML comparison tool).

Then you could also automate this part by having some code or tool perform the test and report.

I have done it with SOAP UI in the past: You can build a test case where SOAP UI feeds your input to Biztalk and waits for Biztalk output (provided you can redirect Biztalk to call SOAP UI instead of the service). Then it can perform the comparison on its own too.